# Create table of contents from headings

Tags: angular, tableofcontents

**In Angular, how can I create a table of contents from the heading elements on the page?**

HTML:

```
<article id="page">

    <ul id="page-toc">
       <!-- auto-generated toc-items go here -->
    </ul>

    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>

    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>

</article>
```

TS:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    createToc() {
        let elemArticle = document.getElementById("page");
        var myArrayOfNodes = [].slice.call( elemArticle.querySelectorAll("h2") );

        var toc = document.getElementById("page-toc");

        myArrayOfNodes.forEach( function(value, key, listObj) {
            var li = toc.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
            li.innerHTML = value.innerHTML;
    })

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createToc();
    }
}
```

This runs without error and the li elements do appear on the page. However, the css defined in my-component.scss does not get applied to them. This leads me to believe that Angular doesn't really know about the auto-generated li elements.

What is the Angular way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can add class to your li by using:

```
li.className = "test"
```

and set style to test class in your global styles.css of your src folder, for e.g in your styles.css:

```
.test{
  color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9q2cab)

or you can  Prefix your css with :host /deep/, in your component css:

```
:host /deep/ .test{
  color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhmxpf)

or Set the encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.None` and use component css:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**update**:

you can define a tocPage child in your html and send the titles to tocPage to list them in the page:

app-component.html:

```
<article id="page">    
    <page-toc [elements]="titles"></page-toc>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>

    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
</article>
```

app-component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  public titles: string[] = []
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){
      this.createToc();
  }
  createToc() {
    let elemArticle = document.getElementById("page");
    var myArrayOfNodes = [].slice.call( elemArticle.querySelectorAll("h2") );
    console.log(myArrayOfNodes)
    myArrayOfNodes.forEach((value, key) => {
      this.titles.push(value.innerHTML)
    })
  }
}
```

page-toc.component.ts

```
export class PageToc  {
  @Input() elements: string[];
}
```

page-toc.component.html

```
<ul id="page-toc">
  <li class="title" *ngFor="let element of elements">
    {{element}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

page-toc.component.css:

```
.title{
  color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhmxpf).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I would like it to use the styles defined in the corresponding component style file as stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks, while `ul#page-toc {
        ::ng-deep li {
            color: red;
        }
    }` will do the job, I am looking for how to change my above javascript example to a method that doesn't require me to use these kinds of tricks.

Comment: if you are adding the article and titles dynamically and user creates them so you can add the page-toc element dynamically when the new title is added.